# Hyperlink to web page in QLabel using PySide

Tags: python, hyperlink, pyside, qlabel

I am having troubles displaying a functional hyperlink to a web page in a QLabel using PySide (Python version 3.2.5). Reading the most upvoted answer from this post [c++ - Making QLabel behave like a hyperlink - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427446/making-qlabel-behave-like-a-hyperlink), I was under the impression that this would work:

```
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication([])
window = QLabel()
window.setText("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\" />Stack Overflow</a>")
window.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
window.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)
window.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Unfortunately, the text does not show up as a link. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: In the example, the `<a>` tag has been made self-closing, and so there's no link text.

Comment: Yes; not sure how this happened, I thought I just copy-pasted the tags... Sorry for bothering you with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link are broken, Fix it should be fine;

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel

myQApplication = QApplication([])
myQLabel = QLabel()
myQLabel.setText('''<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a>''')
myQLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
myQLabel.show()
myQApplication.exec_()
```