# Make a Label/Text automatically recognize links in QtQuick/QML?

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qml

I want to automatically make links (e.g. https://xmpp.org/) into the text of a Text element clickable, so the link can be opened in a browser (without manually copying the link).

I can't add e.g. `<a href="https://xmpp.org/"></a>` manually in my code, because the input comes directly from users.

Has Qt a simple solution for this in QtQuick/QML?

Comment: What kind of element are you using ?, Are you using TextEdit or another element?

Comment: If you know how to create a link in a label, just use regex to recognize whether the input is URL.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427446/making-qlabel-behave-like-a-hyperlink

Comment: For clarification: You want the user to input a link then turn that link into a hyperlink?  Using a `QLabel`?

Comment: If you're using a QLabel, you can do something like `myLabel->setText(myLabel->text().replace("https://xmpp.org/", "<a href=\"https://xmpp.org/\"></a>");`.

Comment: I'm using QML for the GUI (not QWidgets).

Comment: I'm developing an instant messaging client, and I want to make all links in my chat highlighted and clickable.

Comment: @LNJ If you tell us what element you are using in your chat we could help you, but the question will be closed because it is broad.

Comment: @eyllanesc op told us in the title and in the body of the question, `Label` and `Text` are Qt Quick components used in QML. This question is very clear.

Comment: @GrecKo Thanks. :) I use a special Label (from Kirigami), but it is just changes some simple design properties of the Qt Quick Templates Label, that is based on the normal `Text` element. The answer hasn't to be for this special case, one for the normal Qt Quick `Text` element is enough!

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like that(Regex is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701911/165905));

```
Text {
   property string text2: "http://www.google.com"
   text: isValidURL(text2) ? ("<a href='"+text2+"'>"+text2+"</a>") : text2
   onLinkActivated:{
       if (isValidURL(text2)){
          Qt.openUrlExternally(text2)
       }
   }
   function isValidURL(str) {
      var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
      return regexp.test(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextArea` or `TextEdit` components, set `textFormat` property to `TextEdit.RichText` and listen to `onLinkActivated` signal.

E.g.

```
TextArea {
  id: ...
  
  textFormat: TextEdit.RichText 

  onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally( link )
}
```

Note: in order the link in browser you need to use `Qt.openUrlExternally`

One hint, in order to make the component not editable (so that user can not type in), DO NOT set `enabled` property (inherited from Item) to false, use `readOnly` property instead. Setting `enabled` would make link unclickable.

Comment: This is a good option, but unfortunately it does not automatically turn "http://…" text into links as well.