# Need to activate hyperlink in QLabel in Qt

Tags: qt

We are working on Qt Framework and we need to implement a dialog in which we have to show hyperlink in qlabel but hyper link is not activated in dialog.
Please suggest us.

Regards,
Gaurav Badgujar.

Comment: did you set the [openExternalLinks](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop) property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making QLabel behave like a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427446/making-qlabel-behave-like-a-hyperlink)

Comment: I used Qlabel in .cpp file and set test in .ui file also coneect signal linkactivated and set property setOpenExternalLinks(true) in .cpp file but link not activated.

Comment: provide a [mcve]